# Redirect after printing PHP

Tags: php, printing

I want to redirect to a page, after user click print and the printing proses is finish. can it be achieved?

This is my simple code.

```
<?php
include('include/conn.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "select * from barcode where b_acc_no_code = '".$id."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$path = $row['b_path'];

echo '<img src="'.$path.'.jpg" />';
echo '<script>window.print();</script>';
//header('location: barcode.php');
}
?>
```

As you can see, i commented the redirect code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `header()` function will not work if the php already output anything. The header should be sent before any output.

You may use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://yourdomain.com/path/to/barcode.php">
```

in the HTML of the page which will redirect in 5 second after loading completes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried this and it works like a charm. simple yet effective! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't use header function when you already print something on the webpage. (Header must come before any content) and that's why you can't do this.

A workaround for this, is redirect via javascript, like this:

```
echo '<script>self.location = "barcode.php";</script>';
```

You may use [headers_sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function to check if you can use header function or not, but it's just a matter of planning. In your code, using JS will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

header should be defined first as you are not using output buffer.